# Resizing scroll view with auto layout?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, frame, autolayout

It's a common technique to wrap content in a `UIScrollView` for the purpose of moving it out of the way when a keyboard appears. This is done by modifying the frame/bounds of the scroll view, so that it encompasses the area not covered by the keyboard. According to [Ole Begemann](http://oleb.net), one [shouldn't use the `frame` property when using autolayout](http://oleb.net/blog/2013/03/things-you-need-to-know-about-cocoa-autolayout/).

How does one accomplish this same effect without using frame?

Comment: Just wondering, did you figure this out already?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an outlet to your constraint(s) in IB, e.g. to the constraint that connects the bottom of the `UISCrollView` to the superview, and then use code to change the constant of that constraint. This can also be animated in an animation block.

```
        self.someConstraint.constant = ...;
```